# In Cypress when running multiple spec files together the imports on each spec file are imported multiple times. Overwrites then call themselves

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I have a multiple specs files in Cypress and each one imports a file named "helper.cy". helper.cy contains a Cypress.Commands.overwriteQuery overwriting the "contains" query.

When I try to run all the spec files together (there are 8), the contains overwrite calls itself 8 times. Presumably this is because the way that Cypress merges the spec files together, it ends up importing helper.cy 8 times.

Has anyone else experienced this and does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Generally helper files are classed as "Support" files and are placed in (or imported into) the index or root file of the folder `cypress/support`. By default that file is `cypress/support/e2e.js` but you can configure it to be another file in `cypress.config.js`.

See this page of the documentation [Writing and Organizing Tests](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file)

> **Support file**
>
> To include code before your test files, set the supportFile path.
>
> This file runs before every single spec file.
> We do this purely as a convenience mechanism **so you don't have to import this file**.